# Prolog - Custom 'if-then-else'

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I'm experimenting with Prolog and tried to make my own "**`if-then-else`**" method, so that I don't use the `-> ;` method, for experimenting's sake.
My goal is to make it so that there can be nested ifs and elses in my code if required.
Thus far I have got this:

```
ifthenelse(_, G, G):- G.    %no matter the condition, the goals are the same
ifthenelse(true,G,_):- G.   %if
ifthenelse(false,_,G):- G.  %else
```

I think my way hardly seems correct. How can I make my own `ifthenelse/3` properly?

Thank you

Comment: Do not make an `ifthenelse/3` rule. Prolog is not [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). Don't think 'how` think `relationship`. If you want to learn how to avoid `-> ;` then understand that `,` is a logical and, and that predicates with the same signature are logical or. That combined with [guard rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) should get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Preface**: What you have implemented is, in an important way, **a lot better** than the built-in construct you mentioned. I will discuss this point in more detail below.

Regarding the **literal** question: I think you are *quite close* already, since  you can already *nest* this to some extent:

```
?- ifthenelse(C1, ifthenelse(C2,X=1,X=2), X=3).
C1 = C2, C2 = true,
X = 1 ;
C1 = true,
C2 = false,
X = 2 ;
C1 = false,
X = 3.
```

What now remains is to make it nestable **in the condition**. For this, you need a way to *reify* the outcome of conditions, that is, to turn the truth value into a Prolog *term* that you can reason about symbolically.

See `if_/3` for more information: [**Indexing `dif/2`**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590)

A key property this construct preserves is called [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity). In particular, do not erroneously commit to one branch if both are logically possible!

---

**Note on purity**: From a declarative point of view, what you have implemented is very nice and has a clear logical interpretation. Taking for example the last two clauses, we can read `ifthenelse(C,G1,G2)` as: *If* `C` is `true`, then the predicate holds if `G1` holds. If `C` is `false`, then it holds if `G2` holds. Perfectly fine. A semantic "if...then" is not in any way problematic; in fact, every single Horn clause can be read in this way, as an implication from right to left.

In contrast, the built-in construct you mention *lacks* such a declarative reading in general. For example:

```
?- ( ( X = 1 ; X = 2 ) -> true ; true ).
X = 1.
```

But on the other hand:

```
?- X = 2, ( ( X = 1 ; X = 2 ) -> true ; true ).
X = 2.
```

So *adding a constraint* has led to a *new* solution. A classical logician's nightmare.

Your construct *avoids* such problems, because it does not prematurely **commit** to any particular branch. This yields a much more versatile predicate that can also be used in other directions. For example, see that **all** possible solutions are correctly generated:

```
?- ifthenelse(C, true, true).
true ;
C = true ;
C = false.
```

So, I highly encourage your way of formulating this: As you have made perfectly clear, it's **your own** 'if-then-else', and you are using only pure monotonic constructs to express it.

On a psychological note, I generally prefer to give more room to pure declarative constructs and I added this section only because the comments expressed genuine interest in these aspects.

Comment: The answer above was helpful, and I wil take both your replies into consideration; is it really so disastrous, implementing or using `if then` logic in Prolog codes?

Answer (score 2):

It is known that in order to avoid `->` and implement it yourself, you need to use cut (`!`) to simulate same behavior:

```
if_then_else(P, Q, R) :- P, !, Q.
if_then_else(P, Q, R) :- R.
```

where `P` is the condition `Q` the then part and `R` the else part.

Comment: does this support nested `if`s?

Comment: Yes it is exact equivalent of classic if then else `->;`